# Retrieve value from x++ outside of a function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem!

I need to retrieve the value of score++ outside of its function.

For example, if the user clicks "button" 5 times I want the score result to be 5.

How to use this result in a new function?

I searched without finding a solution.

```js
let score = 0;
let clickHere = document.getElementById("clickHere");

clickHere.addEventListener("click", () => {
score++;
// console.log(score)
// Add 1 when I click
});

console.log(score);
// Score = 0
```

```css
#clickHere {
padding: 20px;
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickHere">Click here !</div>
```

:).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMMAV.png)

Comment: It is adding 1 each time you click!

Comment: One solution would be to update the UI in your function when the score increments.

Comment: This is not possible. Everything outside of the function executes *before* the user clicks. So just put the code that needs the updated value *inside* the function.

Comment: We live in a universe that operates with linear time. You can’t use the result of clicking on the button 5 times **before** the button has been clicked on at all.

Answer (score 1):

The console log outside the callback is executed only once. For every click, the event listener callback is executed. You can do all changes related to the variable there.

```js
let score = 0;
let clickHere = document.getElementById("clickHere");
let counterDiv = document.getElementById("counter");

clickHere.addEventListener("click", () => {
  score++;
  counterDiv.innerText = "Counter: " + score;
  // console.log(score)
  // Add 1 when I click
});

console.log(score); // --> Already executed due to asynchronous nature
// Score = 0
```

```css
#clickHere {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickHere">Click here !</div>
<h4 id="counter">Counter: 0</h4>
```

Comment: As I have already said, getting the log outside the event listener to update is impossible as JavaScript is asynchronous and the log does not wait for a click to happen. @Marie

Comment: I don't get what localstorage is doing here